I am creating a table in Google Docs via API; is it possible to rotate only the table landscape and keep other content as it is?
I am dynamically generating a table in Google Docs using the Google Docs API, with the table data provided in JSON format from an API. I need to rotate the table landscape. I have text paragraph also on the pages but I want it as it is. How can I implement this using Java in a Spring Boot application?

And I want to display my table as

So I will get more space to write my column title.

Please provide a minimal reproducible example. Kindly show us your current situation and your expected result so that community members will have visualization on your end goal.

I have updated my description with example

I do think that rotating a table wouldn't be possible. AFAIK you need to turn the table into an image first, paste it on your docs then rotate it to be able to achieve your end goal. however, there are some struggles as you have to resize your text/title before converting it into an image. Moreover, if you think that this is a necessary feature, you can request it via issuetracker.com
